# is there any possibility to use symbolic variables in the for loop?

Tags: matlab, variables

I have some symbolic variables in for loop then an error appears which is

```
??? The following error occurred converting from sym to double:
  Error using ==> mupadmex
  Error in MuPAD command: DOUBLE cannot convert the input expression into a double array.
    If the input expression contains a symbolic variable, use the VPA function instead.
```

The problem is that I should plug the value of symbolic variable at the end of calculation, because they are integration variables... how can I solve this problem???

```
function [product,Mi]=test(ii)
variables % this is just a numerical value for m, M and L
syms x y q B alp kk

product=zeros(3,1);
for i=1:3
for ni=1:9

n=new(ni); % All possible "n"s for each "ni" here new(ni) a function which gives different size matrix each time in the for loop 

n_vector=zeros(1,3);

for jj=1:size(n,1)

    n_vector(:)=n(jj,:);




p_vector=((2*pi/L)*(n_vector));
q_vector=((L/(2*pi))*[1,0,0]);
A=zeros(1,3);

    if ii==1
        Mi=sqrt(x.^2*M^2+(1-x).*m^2);
        A=y.*p_vector;
    elseif ii==2
        Mi=sqrt(m^2-(x.*(1-x)).*q^2);
        A=x.*q_vector;
    elseif ii==3
        Mi=sqrt((y.^2).*(M^2-(x.*(1-x)).*q^2)+(1-y).*m^2);        
        A=y.*(p_vector-q_vector*x);
    elseif ii==4
        Mi=sqrt((1-y).^2*M^2+y.^2*m^2-(x.*(1+x)).*y^2*q^2);    
        A=(1-y).*p_vector-(x.*y).*q_vector;
    end

        if i==1
           product(i,1)=A(1,1)*n_vector(1,1)    
        else
           product(i,1)=A(i,1)*n_vector(1,i)
        end

end
end
end
end
```

here just a part of my function... I know "product" looks weird, I mean I can write an expression without for loop ,but actually in my function I need a for loop here each product like that...

Comment: At exactly what line does the error occur, and why do you define them a symbols? I only see you do numerical calculations.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you cannot assign `A(1,1)*n_vector(1,1)` to `product(i,1)` is because `product` has been defined as a double array.

Will not work:

```
product = zeros(3, 1)
product(1,1) = sym('A')

  The following error occurred converting from sym to double:
  Error using mupadmex
  Error in MuPAD command: DOUBLE cannot convert the input expression into a double array.
  If the input expression contains a symbolic variable, use the VPA function instead.
```

Will work:

```
product=cell(3,1);
product(i,1) = {sym('A')}
product(2,1) = {sym('B')}
product(3,1) = {sym('C')}
```